# C# Is Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.Cell.Count a calculated for every call or a constant

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2003

I have some code where I check whether there are any cells in my Excel.Range by checking the property Excel.Range.Cells.Count. Judging from my profiling this seems to be a bottle neck (note that the method is called a lot of times). Does anyone know how the Count property is implemented, is it calculated by iterating through all cells on every call, or is it a constant?

I cannot find anything about this in Microsoft's documentation, on StackOverflow or Google. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As Excel.Range.Cells returns a Range object itself the property of Range is used. And its documentation says that it returns the number of object within a collection. [MSDN][1]

This indicates that range is like a dynamic array and as such its Count Property cannot be constant (in the sense of C style constant). Thus we can infer that the property is calculated with each call, at least by reading an internally stored value which is only updated when the collection changes.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214230(v=office.11).aspx